# Eclipse C++ formatter puts new line before method identifiers

Tags: eclipse, formatting, eclipse-cdt

I ran into a problem with the Eclipse formatter.  It won't format my code correctly when declaring methods within a class declaration.  It puts a new line after the method's return type.

I already exported the style xml file and examined the settings in it, but none of the settings have any apparent connection to this problem, and the settings editor in Eclipse didn't show the same problem happening in it's sample code for method declarations.

Here is an example bit of code for what I want to have happen:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass();
        void myMethod();
};
```

However, this is what I get:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass();
        void
        myMethod();
};
```

Again, in the styles editor, the code doesn't have this problem and looks just how I want it to, but in the actual code, the story is different.

I'm using version 3.8.0.  Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I deleted those source files that were formatted incorrectly (after formatting the code several times to no avail) and replaced them with "identical" files with the same methods, same structure, etc.  I formatted the code this time and it worked.  This is probably a bug, but I'm leaving it up just in case anyone else encounters a similar problem or has a solution to avoiding this problem in the first place.

Comment: Similar problem emerges eight years on with **Nsight Eclipse 10.2** and **Eclipse CDT version: 8.4.0.nvidia-qualifier**. The solutions below (to date) do not work for me and I have posted a fresh question at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61257074/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I hand edited two files under the main eclipse projects directory

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings
```

The two files:

```
file 1: org.eclipse.cdt.core.prefs, change this line from "insert" to "do not insert"
 org.eclipse.cdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_before_identifier_in_function_declaration=do not insert


file 2: org.eclipse.cdt.ui.prefs,
scan this file for "insert_new_line_before_identifier_in_function_declaration" and make a similar change from insert to do not insert next to it, should be obvious
```

Note I seen this problem on indigo and juno, the fix described above was in juno.

Comment: Same problem in Kepler, solved with this technique. Why is this not in the Preferences menus?

Comment: Why isn't this in the preferences menu, the default (break for no good reason) is horrible.

Comment: This still exists in Luna. The above modifications solve the issue. This should be a setting within Eclipse.

Comment: Can you explain how to change this via the Eclipse UI?

Comment: Still no UI option in Mars. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a custom formatter config, export it first (settings>C/C++ General>Formatter>Edit>Export). Then change the following line to "do not insert". Save the XML.

```
<setting id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_before_identifier_in_function_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
```

Delete the current config and import the one you changed.

Comment: Can you explain how to change this via the Eclipse UI?

Answer (score 0):

There's a specific preference in the formatter options starting from cdt 9.8 included in Eclipse 2019-06.

Answer (score 0):

Others have adequately explained how to fix the problem, but that leaves open the question of *why* line breaks are inserted by default. I hope the following helps.

Line breaks before function names is a *very* long-stand tradition in C, and some common tooling relies on it.

For example, `vi` and its derivatives have a keyboard shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> for "jump to definition" that uses an external cross reference list, which is generated by the `ctags` program, and many versions of `ctags` rely on C function names  being on the left margin.

In hindsight this should have been disabled right from the start when dealing with C++, because there are too many aspects that are different.

In particular, line breaks before method names inside a class are less useful because, since they're indented, they won't be recognized by `ctags` and other tools. Worse, line breaks on declarations that are not definitions are entirely useless, as they distract from finding the actual definitions.